# why DOM is null when evaluated in a callback function of an ajax call using jQuery.get()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I run this function to get the contents of a html inside the div #contents with success. But when I use the deferred.always callback function any DOM elements  are null ( included window! ).
Could someone explain why and what is the solution? Thanks.

```
 function loadHomec(){
$.get("../ajax/homec.html", function(data) {

$(contents).html(data);


}).always(function() {
    console.log(window.document.getElementById('myId').value);
});
}
```

The data returned from homec.html is like the following :

```
       <p>
Welcome 

</p> <ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#"  onclick="loadNewType()">Create New Object Type</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#" onclick="loadtreeForTypes()">Create New Object</a></li> 
    <li>
        <a href="#">Create New RulesSet</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Did you first already defined `var contents = $('#contents')` outside the function?

Comment: @Satpal contents is a div in the page which call the function <div id="contents"></div>.

Comment: How does the `data` look like? Add it to your question.

Comment: @fuyushimoya no I didn't but it works and load the contents of the html page requested into the div contents.

Comment: So the `window` in you `console,log` is also null?

Comment: @fuyushimoya yes it is

Comment: I've created a simple [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4exqf229/) for you, it seems work and able to get the `window` and its childs, please edit it so that to make the template fits your problem, otherwise we might not be able to help.

Comment: @fuyushimoya your jsfiddle fails in my browser even if I put some value into the divs ...

Answer (score 0):

This [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/ddbvxmg5/) shows that everything works fine unless you have an exception in your success handler. Which is a candidate, since you still haven't provided how `content` is defined. Given you have jquery in your project it's doubtful you read the DOM object with vanilla js and I expect the code should look like `$('#contents').html(data);`

Comment: But he says the `window` is `null`, it he can assure that, it means the always it reached, while in your jsfiddle, a error cause always never get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Only `Input`, will have the attribute `value`, for other dom elements, you need to get the text by `innerText`, `innerHTML`.

And if you have already used jQuery, why not just use `$('#myId').text()` or `$('#myInput').val()`?

```js
function loadHomec(){
    $.get("./", function(data) {
        console.log('Do!');
    }).always(function() {
        console.log('Always!');
        console.log(window.document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML);
        console.log(window.document.getElementById('myId').innerText);
        console.log(window.document.getElementById('myInput').value);
    });
}
loadHomec();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contents"></div>
<div id="myId">This is a div</div>
<input id="myInput" value="This is a text"/>
```

Comment: meh! so you lied to me that `winodw` is `null`, which I don't know how it could be :P

Comment: @fuyushimoya which as a web developer you should definitely know :) `window` is a global object how can it be not accessible? You can't even reassign it. The only way is to run javascript under Node.js

Comment: @KirillSlatin So I what mean is 'I don't know how a `window` can't be accessible in a seems-on-broswer code'. Well, that means some joking, which should not be appear here, sorry that made you serious.